# What Sorts of Clients Can't Easily Connect to HTTPS URLs?

Tags: security, oauth, compatibility, ssl

I am wondering what sorts of clients (programming platforms or devices) can connect to http://... URLs, but have difficulty connecting to https://... URLs?

That's all I'm asking really, but in case you're wondering *why* I'm asking, here's **a little background:**

I'm building a REST(ish) API, and I've been agonizing over how best to do client authentication.  I keep changing my mind about whether to use:

1. an OAuth 1.0a sort of approach where each API user has a secret key that they use to sign API requests (with HMAC-SHA1 or HMAC-SHA256), sending a base-64-encoded signature (but not the key) along with each request; or
2. an OAuth 2.0 sort of approach where all communication happens over TLS/SSL, and each user's secret key (or access token, or whatever you want to call it) is sent along with each request.

I know that there are pros and cons to each approach.  A key advantage of option 2, which requires all API endpoints to be HTTPS URLs, is that it's considerably simpler.  I believe the simplicity of this approach is one of the main reasons that it's the default in OAuth 2.0.

But it's only simpler if accessing HTTPS URLs is not an obstacle for the client software.  Which is why I'm wondering **what sorts of clients will find it unfeasible to use an API that forces HTTPS on them?**

I know of one: HTTP web pages that want to connect to a JSON API using JavaScript running in the browser.  They can't access any HTTPS URLs without triggering browser security warnings about mixed content.

But I'm sure there must be other problem clients or programming platforms.  Maybe old versions of PHP, or shared hosts, embedded devices, old Win32 apps, some sorts of enterprise middleware software etc.?  (Just some possible ideas.  I'm really not sure if clients with limited support for HTTPS connections are a practical problem or more of a theoretical one.)

Comment: Don't forget the different trusted root CAs available on different platforms. Especially on smartphones the list of trusted root CAs is often much shorter that on desktop operating systems and web-browsers.

Comment: Good point, thanks Robert.  I had wondered if support for root certs might vary across platforms, so it's useful to know that they do.  Presumably I can circumvent that issue by going with a one of the major CA's for my server certificate, though that's something I'll have to look into when choosing.